# How to execute the second Iterarion of Data in excel using Openpyxl with Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to read data from my Excel spreadsheet and so far i have been able to do it using the code below but i cant run iterations.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np

wb = load_workbook('c:\ExcelData\pyExcel.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
table = np.array([[cell.value for cell in col] for col in ws['A2':'A3']])
print(table)
```

Another Example:

```
val1=2
val2=1
wb = load_workbook(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'c:\ExcelData\pyExcel.xlsx')))
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
c = sheet.cell(row=val1, column=val2).value
d = sheet.cell(row=val2, column=val2).value
print(c) 
print(d)
```

So far what this does is to read a harcoded row and cell from an excel file and print or assign the value to a variable, But I am looking for a way to run iterations of data.. I want to use it as a data table when the first rows of all the columns will be executed the first time and then at the end the script will start over again but using the next row.

Thanks.

Comment: openpyxl does provide `max_row` and `max_column` properties for worksheets. Maybe you can use those. I'm afraid it's not quite clear what you want to do.

Comment: Hi, I think the best way to describe what i am looking for are Datatables in Quick Test pro. If you see the example on this page http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_datatables.htm. See the example given on the tutorial you will see that you can chose if you want to run 1,2 or N rows.  The first time the script with use all the info inside the first row and then the next, so in this case if you have more than 1 user you can run the data inside your spreadsheet many times but using different data. I dont know if this is better. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do. Please rephrase the question to ask something specific about the openpyxl library not "how can I do qtp using Python?"

Comment: I will try to simplify the question,  I have an spreadsheet in excel and i am just able to read and use the data inside the hardcoded row A1.. I want to run the script a second time but using the data inside the row A2.  In Automation testing you will run a script several times using different data, but i haven't been able to understand how to do this with openpyxl. You can always go back to the example above and ask "How can i do something like this using openpyxl"

Answer (score 0):

pinky you should use variables into the table = np.array([[cell.value for cell in col] for col in ws['A2':'A3']])

example ws['variable':'variable']]) or ws['ANUMBERVARIABLE':'ANUMBERVARIABLE']])

Answer (score 0):

@Pinky Read this page http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html and try to find your answer. If you still did not understand from it, I'll try to help you with a code. I feel this is the best way you could actually learn what you are doing rather than just receiving the code directly.